# Azure DevOps Server is unable to create an Azure resource using a Service Principal which is a Contributor to the subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I am following the tutorial [Implementing Terraform on Microsoft Azure](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/implementing-terraform-microsoft-azure/discussion) to the letter. So far so good and I have reached the module where terraform workspaces are used to create environments from the Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline. The module name is "Using Azure DevOps"

The Azure DevOps project is public - https://dev.azure.com/MarkKharitonov0271/_git/Globomantics-testing

Running the [workspaces](https://dev.azure.com/MarkKharitonov0271/Globomantics-testing/_release?definitionId=1&view=mine&_a=releases) release pipeline consistently fails for me:

```
2020-01-19T03:23:20.5420275Z Error: authorization.RoleDefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c' with object id '0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write' over scope '/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
2020-01-19T03:23:20.5420512Z 
2020-01-19T03:23:20.5420989Z   on vnet-peering.tf line 52, in resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vnet-peering":
2020-01-19T03:23:20.5421339Z   52: resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vnet-peering" {
```

(You can view the vnet-peering.tf in the project repo - https://dev.azure.com/MarkKharitonov0271/_git/Globomantics-testing?path=%2Fnetworking%2Fvnet-peering.tf)

Anyway, if I understand the error message correctly, it claims that the Service Principal `0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c` does not have the rights to create a new role definition in the subscription `2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3`

So, I checked the Service Principal:

```
PS /home/mark> az ad sp show --id '0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c'
{
  "accountEnabled": "True",
  "addIns": [],
  "alternativeNames": [],
  "appDisplayName": "MarkKharitonov0271-Globomantics-testing-2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
  "appId": "0ae4ffc7-149d-45ac-ab15-c9f61e4591f8",
  "appOwnerTenantId": "717e5a4d-529c-4ab2-a1c5-6a5f6345d8e4",
  "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
  "appRoles": [],
  "applicationTemplateId": null,
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "displayName": "MarkKharitonov0271-Globomantics-testing-2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "homepage": "https://VisualStudio/SPN",
  "informationalUrls": {
    "marketing": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "support": null,
    "termsOfService": null
  },
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "notificationEmailAddresses": [],
  "oauth2Permissions": [
    {
      "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access MarkKharitonov0271-Globomantics-testing-2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3 on behalf of the signed-in user.",
      "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access MarkKharitonov0271-Globomantics-testing-2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
      "id": "d0f141b9-fc6b-4f3c-9217-018d74712ee1",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access MarkKharitonov0271-Globomantics-testing-2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3 on your behalf.",
      "userConsentDisplayName": "Access MarkKharitonov0271-Globomantics-testing-2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
    }
  ],
  "objectId": "0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c",
  "objectType": "ServicePrincipal",
  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/717e5a4d-529c-4ab2-a1c5-6a5f6345d8e4/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element",
  "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ServicePrincipal",
  "passwordCredentials": [],
  "preferredSingleSignOnMode": null,
  "preferredTokenSigningKeyEndDateTime": null,
  "preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint": null,
  "publisherName": "Default Directory",
  "replyUrls": [
    "https://VisualStudio/SPN"
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null,
  "samlSingleSignOnSettings": null,
  "servicePrincipalNames": [
    "https://VisualStudio/SPN136d4f76-7262-4ab0-8fbb-7be74dfc803b",
    "0ae4ffc7-149d-45ac-ab15-c9f61e4591f8"
  ],
  "servicePrincipalType": "Application",
  "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
  "tags": [],
  "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Notice that the Service Principal has `appId` equal to `0ae4ffc7-149d-45ac-ab15-c9f61e4591f8`.

And it seems to correspond to the one created by Azure DevOps when I added the Terraform tasks to the pipeline when it wanted to authorize access to the subscription. Indeed:

[image]

Now, the terraform apply step references the same service principal:

[image]

Finally, this Service Principal seems to have Contributor access to the subscription:

```
PS /home/mark> az role assignment list --assignee '0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c'
[
  {
    "canDelegate": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/346f1b92-0621-44c0-b88a-343c52637a0f",
    "name": "346f1b92-0621-44c0-b88a-343c52637a0f",
    "principalId": "0e648d2d-a49f-407e-99de-9d6343876a8c",
    "principalName": "https://VisualStudio/SPN136d4f76-7262-4ab0-8fbb-7be74dfc803b",
    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
    "roleDefinitionName": "Contributor",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
  }
]
PS /home/mark>
```

So, I  do not understand what is going on.

**EDIT 1**

So, I was able to run exactly the same terraform configuration with exactly the same Service Principal from the Azure Cloud Shell.

First I reset the credentials, logged out and logged in back as that Service Principal:

```
PS /home/mark/terraform> az ad sp credential reset --name https://VisualStudio/SPN136d4f76-7262-4ab0-8fbb-7be74dfc803b
{
  "appId": "0ae4ffc7-149d-45ac-ab15-c9f61e4591f8",
  "name": "https://VisualStudio/SPN136d4f76-7262-4ab0-8fbb-7be74dfc803b",
  "password": "e...3",
  "tenant": "717e5a4d-529c-4ab2-a1c5-6a5f6345d8e4"
}
PS /home/mark/terraform> az account clear
Logout successful. Re-login to your initial Cloud Shell identity with 'az login --identity'. Login with a new identity with 'az login'.
PS /home/mark/terraform> az login --service-principal -u https://VisualStudio/SPN136d4f76-7262-4ab0-8fbb-7be74dfc803b -p e...3 --tenant 717e5a4d-529c-4ab2-a1c5-6a5f6345d8e4
Cloud Shell is automatically authenticated under the initial account signed-in with. Run 'az login' only if you need to use a different account
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Visual Studio Enterprise",
    "state": "Enabled",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

Then I cloned the Git repository to obtain the Terraform code and copied over the backend configuration saved from the previous modules:

```
PS /home/mark/terraform> git clone https://MarkKharitonov0271@dev.azure.com/MarkKharitonov0271/Globomantics-testing/_git/Globomantics-testing
Cloning into 'Globomantics-testing'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: We noticed you're using an older version of Git. For the best experience, upgrade to a newer version.
remote: Found 9 objects to send. (2 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
PS /home/mark/terraform> cd ./Globomantics-testing/networking/
PS /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking> dir


    Directory: /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
------           1/19/20  4:41 AM             40 backend.tf
------           1/19/20  4:41 AM           2256 main.tf
------           1/19/20  4:41 AM            436 terraform.tfvars
------           1/19/20  4:41 AM           2423 vnet-peering.tf
------           1/19/20  4:41 AM            279 workspacetest.sh
PS /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking> copy ../../1-main-vnet/backend-config.txt .
```

Now I am ready to initialize Terraform and set the development workspace:

```
PS /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking> terraform init -backend-config='backend-config.txt'
Initializing modules...
Downloading Azure/vnet/azurerm 1.2.0 for vnet-main...
- vnet-main in .terraform/modules/vnet-main


Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
- Downloading plugin for provider "azurerm" (hashicorp/azurerm) 1.41.0...
- Downloading plugin for provider "template" (hashicorp/template) 2.1.2...

...
PS /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking> terraform workspace select development
Switched to workspace "development".
```

Now terraform plan:

```
PS /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking> terraform plan -var sec_client_secret='F...$' -out main.tfplan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.template_file.subnet_prefixes[0]: Refreshing state...
data.template_file.subnet_prefixes[1]: Refreshing state...
data.template_file.subnet_prefixes[2]: Refreshing state...
azurerm_resource_group.main: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet]
data.azurerm_subscription.current: Refreshing state...
module.vnet-main.azurerm_resource_group.vnet: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet]
module.vnet-main.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet]
module.vnet-main.azurerm_subnet.subnet[0]: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet/subnets/web]
module.vnet-main.azurerm_subnet.subnet[2]: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet/subnets/app]
module.vnet-main.azurerm_subnet.subnet[1]: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet/subnets/database]

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_role_assignment.vnet will be created
  + resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vnet" {
      + id                               = (known after apply)
      + name                             = (known after apply)
      + principal_id                     = "63309b8d-908a-4dcf-b95b-25eae33aaceb"
      + principal_type                   = (known after apply)
      + role_definition_id               = (known after apply)
      + role_definition_name             = (known after apply)
      + scope                            = "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet"
      + skip_service_principal_aad_check = (known after apply)
    }

  # azurerm_role_definition.vnet-peering will be created
  + resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vnet-peering" {
      + assignable_scopes  = [
          + "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
        ]
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + name               = "allow-vnet-peer-action-development"
      + role_definition_id = (known after apply)
      + scope              = "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3"

      + permissions {
          + actions     = [
              + "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/write",
              + "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action",
              + "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/read",
              + "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/delete",
            ]
          + not_actions = []
        }
    }

  # azurerm_virtual_network_peering.main will be created
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "main" {
      + allow_forwarded_traffic      = (known after apply)
      + allow_gateway_transit        = (known after apply)
      + allow_virtual_network_access = (known after apply)
      + id                           = (known after apply)
      + name                         = "development_2_sec"
      + remote_virtual_network_id    = "/subscriptions/2b1285d1-f4a7-4cc3-a7b1-0d0fc31d6192/resourceGroups/security/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/security"
      + resource_group_name          = "development-vnet"
      + use_remote_gateways          = (known after apply)
      + virtual_network_name         = "development-vnet"
    }

  # azurerm_virtual_network_peering.sec will be created
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "sec" {
      + allow_forwarded_traffic      = (known after apply)
      + allow_gateway_transit        = (known after apply)
      + allow_virtual_network_access = (known after apply)
      + id                           = (known after apply)
      + name                         = "sec_2_development"
      + remote_virtual_network_id    = "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet"
      + resource_group_name          = "security"
      + use_remote_gateways          = (known after apply)
      + virtual_network_name         = "security"
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

This plan was saved to: main.tfplan

To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
    terraform apply "main.tfplan"
```

And finally terraform apply:

```
PS /home/mark/terraform/Globomantics-testing/networking> terraform apply main.tfplan
azurerm_role_definition.vnet-peering: Creating...
azurerm_role_definition.vnet-peering: Creation complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b9614597-de13-c2c6-a275-9186847642ed]
azurerm_role_assignment.vnet: Creating...
azurerm_role_assignment.vnet: Creation complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/7f6a642d-d43e-05b5-cf34-3d20d02cd255]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.main: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.sec: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.main: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.sec: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.main: Creation complete after 11s [id=/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet/virtualNetworkPeerings/development_2_sec]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.sec: Creation complete after 11s [id=/subscriptions/2b1285d1-f4a7-4cc3-a7b1-0d0fc31d6192/resourceGroups/security/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/security/virtualNetworkPeerings/sec_2_development]

...

Apply complete! Resources: 4 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

resource_group_name = development-vnet
vnet_id = /subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/resourceGroups/development-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/development-vnet
vnet_name = development-vnet
```

And it all works fine using exactly the same Service Principal that was created by Azure DevOps.

I will try next to delete the Service Connection on the Azure DevOps project, create a new one manually and retry the release.

**EDIT 2**

Same error with the new Service Connection. I do not understand it. What I find "curious" is that all the resources in `main.tf` were provisioned just fine, but none in `vnet-peering.tf`.

What is going on here?

**EDIT 3**

Replaced the Terraform tasks by Microsoft DevLabs with those by Charles Zipp, because the Pluralsight course author used them. Same result.

Comment: I have reposted the last edit as an answer - please always post answers as answers. Let me know if would like to post it under your own name - if so I will delete my CW copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because you are trying to modify permissions, that requires `owner` role or custom rbac role.

```
Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor

Comment: Fantastic. But why did it work from the Azure Cloud Shell when I used the same service principal to login?

Comment: I dont really have an answer for this question, but it wouldn't be possible with just contributor access. no idea, sorry

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

Following the understanding that the `Contributor` role is unable to create the role definition and assignment required by the pipeline I have manually enhanced the capabilities of the Service Principal used by the Azure Pipelines.

See below (Azure Cloud Shell running powershell):

```
PS Azure:\> $RoleDef = @{
>> Name = 'AuthWrite'
>> Description = 'Allows to create role definitions and assignments'
>> AssignableScopes = @('/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3')
>> Actions = @('Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write')
>> }
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> az role definition create --role-definition $(($RoleDef | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -replace '"','""')
{
  "assignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3"
  ],
  "description": "Allows to create role definitions and assignments",
  "id": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/be9504ee-704b-4a74-b4e3-3fa9b1ba2a23",
  "name": "be9504ee-704b-4a74-b4e3-3fa9b1ba2a23",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write"
      ],
      "dataActions": [],
      "notActions": [],
      "notDataActions": []
    }
  ],
  "roleName": "AuthWrite",
  "roleType": "CustomRole",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions"
}
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> az role assignment create --assignee https://VisualStudio/SPNf0e6b6b5-984e-4b5b-a6fb-86532ad1b0ce --role 'AuthWrite'
{
  "canDelegate": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/1550bf9a-fcfc-4310-bf3a-3c70fd250578",
  "name": "1550bf9a-fcfc-4310-bf3a-3c70fd250578",
  "principalId": "fac663cd-4e74-4bc9-b685-fb0e182beec2",
  "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
  "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/be9504ee-704b-4a74-b4e3-3fa9b1ba2a23",
  "scope": "/subscriptions/2b38509c-a310-4c8f-bd78-9e400cc874e3",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
}
Azure:/
```

Now that the Service Principal used by the Azure Pipelines has the additional `AuthWrite` I was able to run the pipeline successfully.

Yeehaa!